# How to draw a barplot in r for aggregated columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I added a column to Orange dataset as following:

```
Orange$ageGroup = cut(Orange$age, breaks = c(0,250,900,Inf), labels = c("Young", "Adult", "Old"))
```

Then I applied an aggregate function to create `mean_Orange`:

```
> mean_Orange <- aggregate(. ~ Tree+ageGroup, Orange[,c("Tree","circumference","ageGroup")], mean)
> mean_Orange
   Tree ageGroup circumference
1     3    Young         30.00
2     1    Young         30.00
3     5    Young         30.00
4     2    Young         33.00
5     4    Young         32.00
6     3    Adult         63.00
7     1    Adult         72.50
8     5    Adult         65.00
9     2    Adult         90.00
10    4    Adult         87.00
11    3      Old        125.50
12    1      Old        130.50
13    5      Old        154.50
14    2      Old        183.50
15    4      Old        192.25
```

Now, I'm requested to create a barplot exactly like the following:

[image]

I tried the command below and encountered an error:

```
> ggplot(mean_Orange, aes(x=ageGroup, y=circumference, fill=as.factor(Tree))) + 
+     geom_bar() +
+     coord_flip() # this is used in order to invert the axis orientation
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

Could you please guide me how can I make a plot like above using ggplot library?

Comment: in `geom_bar()` add `stat = 'identity'` to fix the error, and `position = 'dodge'`to have the bars plotted next to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y` is used with `geom_col`:

```
ggplot(mean_Orange, aes(x=ageGroup, y=circumference, fill=as.factor(Tree))) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  coord_flip() # this is used in order to invert the axis orientation
```

You can use `geom_col` with `position="dodge"`.

Comment: Thanks, but it still gives the same error `Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.`